# How to revert to "last known good configuration"

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I failed to install ubuntu 10.04 with WUBI, for some reason it's showing me the root partion is not defined. I'm bored to fight with it so I just removed ubuntu in windows.

However this installation made my original Windows XP cripple, a normal boot will end up with a blue screen, error code 7E, I'm still able to boot with the 'last known good configuration' tho.

My understanding is booting like this will recover things and I'm supposed to be good when reboot, while this is not the case for me, I have to choose the 'boot from last known good configuration' each and every time to work around the blue screen.

Could you suggest how could I resolve this? I feel it's foolish having to waste 10 more seconds each time starting the OS.

Answer (score 1):

can you recover windows using the windows CD?

can you check the disk for damages?

check this article by Microsoft about the same issue
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=321637&sd=RMVP

it shows you how to troubleshoot and to fix if possible

Comment: Thanks for the link, I reviewed things I did when installing ubuntu, the issue's got be some virtual device driver brought into the system by daemon tool. I removed it and the os is OK again.

Thank you.

Comment: would you consider voting up or marking this solution? ;)